# Why does keras.backend.pool3d requires tensor_in to be 5-dimensional?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, tensor, max-pooling

I have the following code

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import backend as K

pool_size = (2,2,2)
strides = (2,2,2)

yt = K.zeros(shape=(10,10,10))

result = keras.backend.pool3d(yt, pool_size, strides, pool_mode="avg")
```

When I try to run the code it says

> .. InvalidArgumentError: tensor_in must be 5-dimensional
>   [Op:AvgPool3D] name: AvgPool3D/

I seem to not like the dimension of yt.
But I want to max pool in 3d image whose dimension is 3x3x3. What should the other dimension be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- batch size
- channels

As every convolution-like operation in Keras, these dimensions are required.

- Using "channels_last" (default): `(batch, size1, size2, size3, channels)`
- Using "channels_first": `(batch, channels, size1, size2, size3)`

So:

```
yt = K.zeros(shape=(1,10,10,10,1))
```